# Class Cast: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

While invoking a http adapter procedure, it popsup a dialog with ProcedureName, Signature and Paramaters and when I hit Run button after entering two string type parameters, I am getting "Class Cast: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable" error.

FYI, I created a worklight adapter using worklight application framework data object editor(automatically generates .xml and impl.js files)

impl.js file

```
function CurrencyConvertor_ConversionRate(params, headers){
    var soapEnvNS;

    soapEnvNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
    var request = buildBody(params, 'xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" ', soapEnvNS);
    return invokeWebService(request, headers);
}



function buildBody(params, namespaces, soapEnvNS){
    var body =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="' + soapEnvNS + '">\n' +
        '<soap:Body>\n';

    body = jsonToXml(params, body, namespaces);

    body += 
        '</soap:Body>\n' +
        '</soap:Envelope>\n';
    return body;
}

function getAttributes(jsonObj) {
    var attrStr = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        var val = jsonObj[attr];
        if (attr.charAt(0) == '@') {
            attrStr += ' ' + attr.substring(1);
            attrStr += '="' + val + '"';
        }
    }
    return attrStr;
}

function jsonToXml(jsonObj, xmlStr, namespaces) {
    var toAppend = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        var val = jsonObj[attr];
        if (attr.charAt(0) != '@') {
            toAppend += "<" + attr;
            if (typeof val  === 'object') {
                toAppend += getAttributes(val);
                if (namespaces != null)
                    toAppend += ' ' + namespaces;
                toAppend += ">\n";
                toAppend = jsonToXml(val, toAppend);
            }
            else {
                toAppend += ">" + val;
            }
            toAppend += "</" + attr + ">\n";
        }
    }
    return xmlStr += toAppend;
}


function invokeWebService(body, headers){
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/CurrencyConvertor.asmx',
        body: {
            content : body.toString(),
            contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };

    //Adding custom HTTP headers if they were provided as parameter to the procedure call 
    headers && (input['headers'] = headers);

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that there is an invalid JSON object somewhere in your code.

Most probably this error raised while converting the body to String using `body.toString()`
as `toString` will return `[object Object]` which is invalid JSON object value (neither valid String nor valid Array)

use `json.stringify(body)` instead, it should make what you intended to do.

besides, try to add some log lines to ease tracing the error